# Checkbox losing value after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, tablesorter

I have a sortable table that uses tablesorter and a parser which allows me to sort checkboxes in checked/unchecked order. I have also added a show values button that displays the values of the selected checkboxes. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/964Hp/9/) everything works as expected. The show values button displays the values correctly before and after sorting.

However, in my website the show values button displays the values only prior to sorting any of the columns. If I sort the table and then try to use the show values button, it doesn't display any of the checkbox values.

I initialize the checkboxes as such:

```
<td>Student with value 25</td>
<td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='cb' id='cb25' value='25' />
</td>
```

The show values button is used to display the values of the checkboxes. This is how it is initialized:

```
<input type="Button" value="Show values" onClick="showVal(this.form)" />
```

And this is the show val function definition in jquery, which displays the alert with the checkbox values:

```
function showVal(table) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i in table.cb) {
        if (table.cb[i].checked) {
            arr.push(table.cb[i].value);
            arr.push("\n");
        }
    }
    alert(arr);
    return arr
}
```

Please let me know what am I missing and/or doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a link to your website? We can't tell what you're doing differently there by looking at the working code.

Comment: One thing that I wonder is why you're not using the exact code for showVal that's in the fiddle you link. You are adding id and name to the array.

Comment: @Barmar the code is exactly the same in that case, however, the behavior changes. Do you think there is something in my code that might behave differently when using PHP?

Comment: Well all the code is client side, so using PHP will not make any difference. Aren't there any Javascript errors in console? Also, if it's possible to provide a link for a page that contains the problem that would be much easier to debug and trace the issue.

Comment: I can't count the number of times someone has posted a question like this, where they swear there's nothing different. When we finally figure it out, there's always something different. Sometimes it's just a typo. Do you load any other libraries in the production site?

Comment: Unfortunately the page where I am trying to make this table work is restricted to public. Anyways, I wrote a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrroboti/5v2rX/2/) which mimics the exact functionality I have on the website! Maybe that will help.

Also, I came accross this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743935/jquery-tablesorter-wont-sort-correctly-if-new-text-is-typed-in-input?rq=1) and it seems to me that I have to bind the checkboxes using the .mouseup function the same way the user Mottie is binding the inputs with the keyup function. Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Dola I tried debugging using the Chrome debugger, basically the issue is what I explained above. Using the interpreter the values of the checkboxes are all "" once I sort, and they are displayed correctly before sorting.

Comment: Does the form get submitted & reload the page when you click on the "Show Values" button? Maybe you need to `return false` at the end instead of `return arr`

Comment: @Mottie just tried that and nothing changes. By using the chrome debugger I see that the values in the checkboxes are not being lost, but the button which is supposed to show the values is not working properly. So the problem is the button, not the table.

Comment: I don't know if this will make a difference, but try the code in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/964Hp/10/)